# Anagram Code in Python - Compare dynamically generated strings to a txt file

Tags: python, io, anagram

I have written an Anagram solving program in Python. I wanted your opinion on whether I had gone about it right. Let me explain the logic:

1. First, the user provides input of two words that he/she wants the single word anagram to be generated for (2 string values)
2. The two are concatenated and there is third value that is derived.
3. The third value is processed by the itertools.permutations function where all possible permutations of the word are derived as a list.
4. The list is formatted with string value being derived from the list.
5. At this point, I have opened a word list that will be used as a dictionary to compare whether the string value is an actual word.
6. The file is read, line by line and the string value is compared with the lines.
7. If a match is found, then the program prints the output on screen as a Dictionary Match

Please tell me if I am going about it correctly or if any improvements can be suggested. Any feedback appreciated. I am new to Python.

Here is the code:

```
    #This program has been created to solve anagram puzzles

# All the imports go here
#import re
import itertools
import fileinput

def anaCore():
    print 'This is a Handy-Dandy Anagram Solving Machine'
    print 'First, we enter the first word....'
    anaWordOnly = False

    firstWord = raw_input('Please enter the first word > ')
    print 'Thank you for entering %r as your first word' % firstWord
    print 'Now we enter the second word....'
    secondWord = raw_input('Please enter the second word > ')
    print 'Thank you for entering %r as your second word' % secondWord

    thirdWord = firstWord+secondWord

    print thirdWord

    mylist = itertools.permutations(thirdWord)

    for a in mylist:
        #print a
        mystr = ''.join(a)
        for line in fileinput.input("brit-a-z.txt"):       
            if mystr in line:
                print 'Dictionary match found', mystr
        #print mystr

anaCore()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as this question is currently written it's rather subjective and directly solicits opinion rather than fact. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) on the kinds of questions to not ask. But don't despair! If you look at the suggestions provided behind that link you can potentially rewrite the question to get the feedback you need.

Comment: just found a google search easter egg thanks to you: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=anagram

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing `mystr =''.join(a)`? why not just do `mystr = a`?

I don't think that `if mystr in line:` is right either, because you could have mystr as, for instance 'dog', and line as 'dogger bank', or something like that. You should probably check for equality instead.

Other than that I can't see anything wrong.

If you wanted to be clever,  you could create a 2st, 3nd, 4th, ... nth dictionary consisting of all combinations of words in the initial dictionary and dictionary n - 1. That way you could find multiword anagrams as well. Don't let n get too big though or the dictionary would take up lots of space.

Comment: I think `itertools.permutations` returns tuples, so you'll have to use some sort of `join` to get the concatenated string, don't you?

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't realise that that was how itertools.permutations worked.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can generate all permutations of words. However, I think it would be more convenient to *sort the letters in the word*. Therefore, you would have to preprocess your whole dictionary, i.e. sort the letters in each word. Then, you just need to check for the sorted sequence of characters.

To simplify: I would generate the sorted sequence of your anagram word. For each line in the file, i would sort it's characters and check if both are the same. If so, check if they were identical words. If they were not identical words, they're anagrams.

Comment: An alternative would be just generate a set from the dictionary, as hashtable lookups are O(1). This way you'd still get all the anagrams and good performance without having to generate a presorted dictionary with anagrams merged or something.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine; calling itertools.permutations on a string is a good way to find matches. Here are just a few thoughts/improvements

- `mylist = itertools.permutations(thirdWord)`: remember that `permutations` does not literally return a list--it returns a generator, which consumes a constant amount of memory (relative to the number of permutations) and produces new permutations on demand. In particular, when you loop over the generator, you produce one permutation at a time. Also, a generator can only produce values in the forward direction--you cannot generally iterate backwards over a generator. Generators are a key concept in Python. See http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators for more information.
- Remember that string comparisons are case sensitive. Assuming your dictionary file is lowercase, you should lowercase your inputs. `s.lower()` returns a lowercased copy of the string `s`.
- Your algorithm for dictionary lookup is inefficient. Look again at your loops. Your outer loop checks every permutation of characters, so it will run n! times where n is the length of your input. But for every permutation, you read every line in the file again. If there are m words in your dictionary, your program requires O(n!*m) work. If you just load your dictionary file into a Python `set`, then the time to look up each permutation is O(1). So your total runtime is O(n!).

Answer (score 1):

Some of my ideas:

The current approach is to first generate all possible permutations of 'thirdWord', then for each permutations, you check if it exists in the dictionary by reading the text file everytime.

You might as well read the dictionary file only once at program's start, put the words into a 'set'. Then, then you can use 'in' to easily check if the permutation exists in the set:

```
>>> a = set(['hello','world','this','is','set'])
>>> 'hello' in a
True
>>> 'python' in a
False
>>>
```

Also, with some long 'thirdWord' it would generate too many permutations. For example, for a word of length 16 with all different letters, it would generate 16! = 20,922,789,888,000 permutations. This is kind of large.

You might reverse the process by iterating the words in dictionary instead, and check for each word if it is anagram with 'thirdWord'. This should be faster than checking with all permutations, for longer words.

Checking for anagram is as easy as:

```
>>> sorted('abc') == sorted('bca')
True
>>> sorted('aab') == sorted('xxx')
False
```